# How to transfer variable from one cpp file to another

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

So I am using object oriented programming. In one .cpp file I have set the values of array for my class. What I'm trying to do is operate with this value in another .cpp file. How do I do that.

This is the .cpp file where I read the values from .txt file and save them into class.

```
#include "branjeDatoteke.h"    
#include "parametri.h"    
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
void branjeDatoteke() {

    Parametri pin[101];
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("pin.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100 && getline(myfile, line); i++)
            {

                pin[i].setPin(line);
               // cout << pin[i].readPin() << endl;
                //cout << line << '\n';
            }
        
        myfile.close();
       // cout <<"tole more delat: "<< pin[2].readPin() << endl;
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";
}
```

And this is the .cpp file where I want to operate with the array I saved before. How do I fix it so it works?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pin.h"
#include "parametri.h"
#include <string>
#include "branjeDatoteke.h"
#include "branjeDatoteke.cpp"
using namespace std;
void pin() {
    string pinKoda;
    cout << "Vnesite pin: ";
    cin >> pinKoda;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        if (pin[i].readPin() == pinKoda) {
            cout << "KODA JE PRAVILNA" << endl;
        }
        if (i > 100) {
            cout << "kode ni v sistemu" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you arrange things so one bit of code calls the other bit? Else you use `extern` to reach a variable defined in a different translation unit.

Comment: I dont quite understand what do you mean. I dont want to use extern since i dont want to use global variables. any other ideas?

Comment: There is no such thing a "transferring" from one file to another in c++. You can either use global variable or pass things by reference to function parameters.

Comment: Please read up on c++ project setup, as you are including a source file (.cpp) in another source file, which is almost always very bad. Also we would need to see the header files (.h) to help with your problem

Answer (score -1):

You can declare a function in the 1st cpp file, which is going to return the values stored in the class, then include the 1st cpp file in the 2nd, and use the same function to receive the values.

Comment: Including a source file (.cpp) in another source file is almost always a really bad idea. It leads to problems in the linking stage of the build process. Declarations used by multiple compilation units should be declared in a header (.h) file.